# MySQL Trigger : Check if primary key ID is in use in other table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to create a trigger for my table `table_master`.

The table schema of `table_master` is simple:

```
master_id       INT(11)       AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY, NOT NULL
title           VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL
```

And here is another relation table `rel_master_another_tbl`

```
master_id       INT(11)       PRIMARY, NOT NULL
another_id      INT(11)       PRIMARY, NOT NULL
```

What I want to achieve is, when a `DELETE` query is issued on `table_master`, the trigger will check whether the `master_id` is used in `rel_master_another_tbl` . **UPDATE:** If yes, rollback / cancel the `DELETE` query.

How can I achieve this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_before_delete BEFORE DELETE ON table_master
// what should I put here?
END;
```

Comment: Check and do what? It seems sketchy to code this up when you can define a foreign key constraint between the tables, with an ON DELETE RESTRICT trigger.

Comment: I would like to stop the DELETE query once found the ID is in use

Comment: that is *precisely* what an ON DELETE RESTRICT trigger does. It stops the query from proceeding if an attempt is made to delete a row in the parent table that the foreign key is referring too.

Comment: can you illustrate how to use `ON DELETE RESTRICT` in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, @ShivanRaptor - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are trying to implement already exists in the database and can be utilized via an `ON DELETE RESTRICT` trigger. An example of defining your tables to take advantage of this is shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE `master` (
    `master_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`master_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `rel_master_another_tbl` (
    `master_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `another_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    KEY `i_master_id` (`master_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY `fk_rel_master_another_tbl_master` (`master_id`)
        REFERENCES `master` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`RESTRICT` in this context means that attempts to delete rows from your `master` table will fail, if there are corresponding rows in your `rel_master_another_tbl` that are referring to masters id column. Also, do note that `RESTRICT` is the default option for both `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` triggers for foreign keys, so you could actually define your foreign key as shown below and it would still function the same:

```
FOREIGN KEY `fk_rel_master_another_tbl_master` (`master_id`)
    REFERENCES `master` (`id`)
```

Refer to the MySQL documentation on [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers & reference links!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if this id exists in another table then you can do that this way:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER check_before_delete BEFORE DELETE ON table_master
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE has_row TINYINT;

SELECT 1
INTO has_row
FROM rel_master_another_tbl
WHERE master_id = OLD.master_id;

IF has_row IS NOT NULL THEN
// PUT YOUR CODE HERE
END IF;

END$$
```

However check Perception's comment about setting key constrain between tables and using `ON DELETE RESTRICT` trigger as this could be proper solution for your problem.